# Ag Grid cell value changed by change detection event

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to create a grid where some of the values may be updated by the user by editing the cell and also the `rowData` can be changed from outside by the application. I'm trying to get an event that allows me to track ALL the changes in my cells, so on every cell change (or row change) I'd like to send an http request. I have tried to use `onCellValueChanged` but it only gets fired when user edits the cell. `onRowDataChanged` doesn't seem to be fired and `onModelUpdated` is fired but it doesn't have any meaningful information like which row/cell has been changed.
I'm not pasting the entire code but there is a function that updates `rowData` with new values every 5 seconds. As far as I understand there is a react renderer that calls `api.setRowData(param)` and `refresh` whenever `rowData` changes. Is there a way to have a callback that is called on every update, no matter if it's user edit or data change with the information what actually has changed? `agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer` already does a nice job of animating the difference, so I'd like to hook on the same event

```
const columnTypes = {
       textColumn: {
         editable: true
        },
        valueColumn: {
            editable: true,
            valueParser: (params: { newValue: any }) => Number(params.newValue),
            cellClass: 'number-cell',
            cellRenderer: 'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer',
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        }
    };

const [data, setData] = useState([] as Array<typeof formData.model>);
    const [logs, setLogs] = useState([] as Array<{ oldValue: string, newValue: string, column: string }>);

    useEffect(() => {
        setData([props.formData.model].map((y, i) => ({ ...y, id: i })));
    }, [props.formData])

           <AgGrid
                onGridReady={onGridReady}
                width="100%"
                stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus
                rowData={data}
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                onCellValueChanged={(params: any) => {
                    setLogs([...logs, { oldValue: params.oldValue, newValue: params.newValue, column: params.colDef.field }])
                }}
                onRowDataChanged ={(params: any) => {
                    console.log(`Changed Values = ${params}`);
                }}
                onModelUpdated={(params: any) =>{
                    console.log("MODEL "+ params);
                }}
                columnDefs={[
                    {
                        headerName: 'Instrument',
                        children: [
                            { headerName: 'Instrument Type', field: 'instrument.instrumentType', ...columnTypes.textColumn },
                            { headerName: 'Price', field: 'market.price', ...columnTypes.valueColumn },
                        ]
                    }
                ]}
                deltaRowDataMode
                getRowNodeId={(d: any) => d.id}
            />
```

Comment: Also looking for a callback for setData. My table is updated on sockets every few seconds. I am looking for how to make animation. Did you succeed?